# How to send a partial HTTP request with curl?

Tags: http, curl

for security research, i would like to send an individual HTTP request fragment using `curl`.

for example, i want to send HTTP headers, without an HTTP body or end segment. is this possible using `curl`?

i have tried `curl -X POST https://localhost`, but that sends a complete request, which is not what i want to test.

Comment: I don't think curl will send an incomplete request.  You might need to use `nc` or `openssl s_client` and manually construct the request.

Comment: Also, it's unclear exactly what you mean and are trying to accomplish.  `GET` requests never have a body, and there's no such thing as an "end segment" in HTTP.  `GET / HTTP/1.1\r\n\r\n` is a complete request.